# setting up hilo in nhibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate

i want to start using hilo. But would really appreciate some help on the steps.  So if i have the following mapping. Do i need to create another table in my database. What would the scheme of this be.

```
<id name="Id" type="Int64" column="cat_id">
        <generator class="hilo">
                <param name="table">hi_value</param>
                <param name="column">next_value</param>
                <param name="max_lo">100</param>
        </generator>
</id>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that schema, you should create (or let NH create, using the `SchemaExport` class) a table named `hi_value`, with a single column, `next_value` which should be an integral type.

If creating it manually, seed it with a single record, containing a **1** (for an empty DB)